# How can I update an image with the press of a button in kivy PYTHON

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

So, I'm kinda new to kivy and I'm trying to make a results screen that will show an image. This image should change with the press of a button. I thought that by changing the source of the image it should update but it doesn't. Here is the most relevant part of my main code:

```
class ResultScreen(Screen, BoxLayout):

    car_list = ObjectProperty(None)
    source_image_list = ['Data/file01.png', 'Data/file02.png']
    i = 0
    source_image = source_image_list[i]

    def increase(self):
        self.i += 1
        self.source_image = self.source_image_list[self.i]
        print(self.source_image)

class Manager(ScreenManager):
    main_screen = ObjectProperty(None)
    loading_screen = ObjectProperty(None)
    results_screen = ObjectProperty(None)

class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        m = Manager(transition=NoTransition())
        return m


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Window.clearcolor = (.46875, .46875, .4765, 1)
    Window.size = (850, 1000)
    MainApp().run()
```

And this is part of my .kv file:

```
<Manager>:
id: screen_manager

    ResultScreen:
        id: resultsS
        name: "Results Screen"
        manager: screen_manager

<ResultScreen>
    orientation: "vertical"
    padding: 10
    spacing: 10
    source_image: self.source_image

    FloatLayout:

        Button:
            text: "Done"
            on_press: root.increase()
            size_hint: 0.3, 0.1
            pos: root.x + 300, root.top - root.height

        Image:
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.5
            source: root.source_image
            pos: root.center_x - (self.width/2), root.center_y - (self.height/4)
```

When I start the application I press the button and "file01.png" is loaded loaded. But when I hit the button nothing changes. The only thing I see is that the source_image path changed in the console. I do not understand why the Image isn't reloaded with the new source. What am I doing wrong?? Please Help me!!

Comment: When your app starts up, your `Image` shows the `root.source_image` image. Then you change `root.source_image`, but your `Image` is still using the old one because it doesn't know that `root.source_image` has changed. Your `increase` function should change the source of your `Image` not the screen's `source` variable. Give your `Image` an `id`, then replace `self.source_image =` with `self.ids['your_image_id'].source = ` (or `self.your_image_id.source =` ) in your `increase` function.

Comment: Hey @Erik, I did what you told me and it worked! Thank you!! I have spent hours trying to fix this and it only took two lines to make it work properly!

Comment: Awesome! Way to go man! Hope it makes sense and you understand how that feature works in the future now :)